# Can I host my own XML file to send data to my android app?

Tags: android, xml, google-drive-api, host

Can I host my own XML file that will send data to my Android app? Are there any easy solutions for this? Host on a google drive account or something?

Comment: Please explain a little more what you are trying to do. If you just need it for debugging you can put it on Google Drive or DropBox and use the link to the file.

Comment: @XaverKapeller : This is just for private use. The app will not be avail on Play Store or anything. I am creating a calculator for my girlfriend. The calculator is to easy calculate prices she will charge for cakes that she makes for her clients. And I will try to make it easy for her to change variables on prices in a XML file, in for example Google Drive, Dropbox etc.

Comment: Well then you pretty much answered your question yourself. Just put it somewhere where the file is easily accessible and retrieve the file when needed.

Comment: @XaverKapeller So I just use URL from Dropbox or google drive then? Answer the question here so I can accept the answer. :)

Comment: Well I would not recommend it in a production environment. But for debugging or in your case personal use it will suffice.